# Set SelectedNode after TreeView.DataBind()

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I'm using ASP.NET TreeView Control in my page. 
I build the tree, by using the CreateChildControls() (override).

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();
        TVOrg = this.FindControl<TreeView>("TVOrg");


        try
        {
            DataTable itemsTable = CreateTable();
            if (itemsTable != null)
            {
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = CreateXML(CreateDataRow(itemsTable));
                if (xmlDoc != null)
                    FillTreeViewFromXML(xmlDoc);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            PNMsoft.Sequence.Diagnostics.DiagnosticUtility.EventLog.LogError(String.Format("TreeViewOrg.aspx:    OnPreRender(), {0}", ex.Message));
        }
    }
```

Inside this method, I'm getting the hierarchy for the tree from an sql view.

```
    public DataTable CreateTable()
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            // base.DbConnection.Open();
            dataTable.Columns.Add(idColumnName);
            dataTable.Columns.Add(ParentColumnName);
            dataTable.Columns.Add(valueColumnName);
            List<DBParameter> prms = new List<DBParameter>();
            dataTable = DBUtil.ExecuteReader("sp_GetTreeViewHierarchy", prms.ToArray(), System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            PNMsoft.Sequence.Diagnostics.DiagnosticUtility.EventLog.LogError(String.Format("TreeViewOrg.aspx:    CreateTable(), {0}", ex.Message));
        }
        return dataTable;
    }
```

after that I'm creating an XML file (in memory) and using the XmlDataSource to bind the data.

```
public DataRow[] CreateDataRow(DataTable table)
    {
        // Use the Select method to sort the rows by ParentID
        DataRow[] SortedRows = null;
        try
        {
            SortedRows = table.Select("", levelColumnName + "," + valueColumnName + "," + ParentColumnName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            PNMsoft.Sequence.Diagnostics.DiagnosticUtility.EventLog.LogError(String.Format("TreeViewOrg.aspx:    CreateDataRow(), {0}", ex.Message));
        }


        return SortedRows;
    }


    public XmlDocument CreateXML(DataRow[] SortedRows)
    {
        // create an XmlDocument (with an XML declaration)
        XmlDocument XDoc = new XmlDocument();
        try
        {
            XmlDeclaration XDec = XDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);
            XDoc.AppendChild(XDec);


            // iterate through the sorted data
            // and build the XML document
            foreach (DataRow Row in SortedRows)
            {
                XmlElement NewNode = XDoc.CreateElement("_" + Row[idColumnName].ToString());
                NewNode.SetAttribute(idColumnName, Row[idColumnName].ToString());
                NewNode.SetAttribute(ParentColumnName, Row[ParentColumnName].ToString());
                NewNode.SetAttribute(valueColumnName, Row[valueColumnName].ToString());


                // special case for top level node
                if (int.Parse(Row[ParentColumnName].ToString()) == 0)
                    XDoc.AppendChild(NewNode);  // root node
                else
                {
                    // use XPath to find the parent node in the tree
                    String SearchString;
                    SearchString = String.Format("//*[@" + idColumnName + "=\"{0}\"] ", Row[ParentColumnName].ToString());
                    XmlNode Parent = XDoc.SelectSingleNode(SearchString);


                    if (Parent != null)
                        Parent.AppendChild(NewNode);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            PNMsoft.Sequence.Diagnostics.DiagnosticUtility.EventLog.LogError(String.Format("TreeViewOrg.aspx:    CreateXML(), {0}", ex.Message));
        }
        return XDoc;
    }


    public void FillTreeViewFromXML(XmlDocument XDoc)
    {
        try
        {
            // we cannot bind the TreeView directly to an XmlDocument
            // so we must create an XmlDataSource and assign the XML text
            XmlDataSource XDdataSource = new XmlDataSource();
            XDdataSource.ID = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();  // unique ID is required
            XDdataSource.Data = XDoc.OuterXml;


            // we want the full name displayed in the tree so 
            // do custom databindings
            TreeNodeBinding Binding = new TreeNodeBinding();
            Binding.TextField = valueColumnName;
            Binding.ValueField = idColumnName;
            Binding.Target = "#";
            TVOrg.DataBindings.Add(Binding);


            // Finally! Hook that bad boy up!       
            TVOrg.DataSource = XDdataSource;
            TVOrg.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            PNMsoft.Sequence.Diagnostics.DiagnosticUtility.EventLog.LogError(String.Format("TreeViewOrg.aspx:    FillTreeViewFromXML(), {0}", ex.Message));
        }
    }
```

I create a new node by filling a form, and than i call this method.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var entityIdHidden = this.FindControl<HiddenField>("SelectedNodeId");


            if (entityIdHidden != null)
                if (entityIdHidden.Value == "")
                    if (!CheckifSiteAlreadyExists())
                        return;


            if (!CheckIfEntityHasParent())
                return;


            var user = AuthenticationManager.LoggedInUser;
            WorkflowAPI api = new WorkflowAPI();


            Dictionary<string, object> entityFields = GetEntityControls();
            AttachmentEntity image = AttchmentItem("AsyncFileUpload2");


            if (image != null)
                entityFields.Add("fldImage", image);


            int entityId = 0;
            bool isSite = CheckIfEntityIsSite();
            if ((entityIdHidden != null) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entityIdHidden.Value)))
            {
                int.TryParse(entityIdHidden.Value, out entityId);
            }
            api.UpdateACtivityFields(WorkflowInstanceId, user, this.GetFormUIViewModel().ActivityInstance, entityFields, entityId, "EntityType");


            List<DBParameter> prms = new List<DBParameter>();
            prms.Add(new DBParameter(System.Data.DbType.Int32, WorkflowInstanceId, "iwf"));
            prms.Add(new DBParameter(System.Data.DbType.Int32, entityId, "entityId"));
            int.TryParse(DBUtil.ExecuteScalar("USP_TEN_Entities_UpdateDynamicsValues", prms.ToArray(),
                CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToString(), out entityId);


            Dictionary<string, object> siteFields;
            if (isSite)
            {
                siteFields = GetSiteControls();
                siteFields.Add("fldParentid", entityId);
                api.UpdateACtivityFields(WorkflowInstanceId, user, this.GetFormUIViewModel().ActivityInstance, siteFields, entityId, "SiteDetails");
            }


            entityIdHidden.Value = entityId.ToString();
            this.CreateChildControls();


            //Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            PNMsoft.Sequence.Diagnostics.DiagnosticUtility.EventLog.LogError(String.Format("TreeViewOrg.aspx:    btnSave_Click(), {0}", ex.Message));
        }
    }
```

This method update the database with the details I've entered.

As you can see in the btnSubmit method at the end, i call the CreateChildControls() method because i need to update the tree with the latest data.
The problem is that i'm losing the focus and SelectedNode.

How can i return to the last Selected Node.

Comment: Its better if you can post your code, so that we can help you easily....

Comment: First of all plz check that your **CreateChildControls()** function is within IsPostBack() condition or not. If yes then go through this link - [http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1997-set-selected-node-on-treeview-asp-net.aspx](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1997-set-selected-node-on-treeview-asp-net.aspx). Plz check and comment...

Comment: Hi, I've used the article you provided and it works. thanks

Comment: All right then...If it helps you then i will enter my comment in answer, so when the other comes to this page in future they will get proper reference and of course you could also give me some up votes. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all please check that your **CreateChildControls()** function is within **IsPostBack()** condition or not. If *yes* then go through this link - [Set Node in Treeview](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1997-set-selected-node-on-treeview-asp-net.aspx%5D%28http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1997-set-selected-node-on-treeview-asp-net.aspx%29) - Which will guide you how to do that.